# Where is Validator::make() method in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've started learning laravel 5.2, I've used this Validator::make($request, $options) method while following [Laravel-5 Quick Start Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart), but I was unable to find this make method in Validator Class or the class it implements, I searched this in all files and found this method in Container Interface, but i don't know how it is hooked to this Validator class.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the facade class reference:

```
Facade      Class                           Service Container Binding
Validator   Illuminate\Validation\Factory   validator
```

`Illuminate\Validation\Factory@make`

[Laravel 5.2 - Facade Class Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades#facade-class-reference)